# I want to add a new drop down in TFS on the screen where bugs are logged. Is there any way to do it?

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to add a new drop down on the bug page in TFS. I want to add a new drop down as 'Bug Fixed In Build' with options as build versions

Thanks

Comment: Any update on this? Did you try my solution below which should works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a **Integration Build** filed for your bug work item type.

> When the **Integration Build** field is present in the WIT definition,
>   Team Foundation Build identifies work items that were resolved with
>   each build and then updates those work items to set the build number
>   in which they were resolved in the Integration Build field.

More detail info please refer this link: [Fields that support integration with test, build, and version control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194965(v=vs.140).aspx)

To display the fields in the work item is also not hard in TFS.  Details please  take a look at this tutorial: [Add or modify a work item type](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-wit). Highly recommend you to install [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)  and use **Process Editor** to modify the work item template.

*Note: To add or customize a WIT, you must be a member of the **Project Administrators group** or have your **Edit project-level** information permission set to **Allow**.*